# Why do some answers on my profile page have a number in parenthesis at the end?

Tags: support, questions

Out of curiosity, why do some answers on my profile page have a number in parenthesis at the end?

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9052/49717373.png.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That means you provided two answers for that question. In the case of the question you pointed out... [Wikimapia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586446/587330#587330) and [SourceForge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586446/586447#586447). Also, the net score shown next to the question is a total of the score for all the answers you provided to that question. In this case 1 for Wikimapia and 2 for SourceForge = 3 that gets displayed.